# Header in QML column

Tags: header, qml

I have this piece of code in QML, but I'm not able to add a STATIC text as the header of each column.

I tried looking online but I don't seem to find the asnwer. Or I just don't get it.

```
Component { 

     id: pedido         
     Item {
         id: item
         width: parent.width;   
         Row {
             id: row
             width: parent.width
             anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                Column {
                        width: parent.width * 0.3                       
                        Text {                          
                            text: " " + codigo;
                            font.family: "Helvetica"                                                                    
                            font.pointSize: 14
                            font.bold: true
                            color: item.ListView.isCurrentItem ? "white" :   "black"                      }
                Column {                            
                        width: parent.width * 0.5   
                        Text {                      
                            text: "     " + nombre;
                            font.family: "Helvetica"                                                               
                            font.pointSize: 14
                            font.bold: true
                            color: item.ListView.isCurrentItem ? "white" : "black"
                            }     
                       }
                Column {
                        width: parent.width * 0.2                           
                        Text {                      
                            text: "     " + fecha;
                            font.family: "Helvetica"                                                               
                            font.pointSize: 14
                           font.bold: true        
    }
}
```

Don't worry if there  are missing `{}` .

Answer (score 1):

You should implement your own `header`. More info in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html).

Let me show you an example with a simple `ListModel`  & `ListView`:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 500

    Rectangle {
        width: 300
        height: 400

        Component {
            id: listDelegate

            Item {
                width: 400;
                height: 50;

                Row {
                    Column {
                        width: 100
                        Text { text: codigo }
                    }
                    Column {
                        width: 100
                        Text { text: nombre }
                    }
                    Column {
                        width: 100
                        Text { text: fecha }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ListModel {
            id: listModel

            ListElement {
                codigo: "111"
                nombre: "AAA"
                fecha: "28/08/2001"
            }
            ListElement {
                codigo: "222"
                nombre: "BBB"
                fecha: "28/08/2002"
            }
            ListElement {
                codigo: "333"
                nombre: "CCC"
                fecha: "28/08/2003"
            }
        }

        ListView {
            id: listView
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: listModel
            delegate: listDelegate
            focus: true
            header: myheader
        }
    }

    Component {     //instantiated when header is processed
        id: myheader
        Rectangle {
            gradient: mygradient
            border {color: "#9EDDF2"; width: 2}
            width: parent.width; height: 50

            Row {
                Column {
                    width: 100
                    Text { text: "Codigo" }
                }

                Column {
                    width: 100
                    Text { text: "Nombre" }
                }

                Column {
                    width: 100
                    Text { text: "Fecha" }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Gradient {
        id: mygradient
        GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#8EE2FE"}
        GradientStop { position: 0.66; color: "#7ED2EE"}
    }
}
```